# Pivot Case Statements into Column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, case

I am not an expert with SQL. I have the below query, what I would like to do is to move the Status as an individual column and count the distinct actionid's.

[image: Action ID Sample image]

Query:

```
SELECT
CONVERT (Date,[ActionTime],103) AS DATE,
COUNT(DISTINCT ActionID) AS Actions,
VehicleID AS VehicleID,
DriverID AS DriverID,
     CASE 
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 7 THEN 'Not Suitable'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 8 THEN 'Job Acknowledged'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 9 THEN 'Job Accepted'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 10 THEN 'Job Rejected'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 12 THEN 'Job Recall'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 66 THEN 'Child Fleet Logon'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 67 THEN 'Child Fleet Logoff'
     ELSE '' END AS Status

FROM [TaxiHistory].[dbo].[Actions]
WHERE actiontime between '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-02 23:59:59'
  AND ActiontypeID IN (7,8,9,10,12,66,67)

  GROUP BY CONVERT (Date,[ActionTime],103),
CASE 
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 7 THEN 'Not Suitable'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 8 THEN 'Job Acknowledged'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 9 THEN 'Job Accepted'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 10 THEN 'Job Rejected'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 12 THEN 'Job Recall'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 66 THEN 'Child Fleet Logon'
     WHEN ActionTypeID = 67 THEN 'Child Fleet Logoff'
     ELSE ''  END,
VehicleID,
DriverID
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: So you want a count of all distinct ActionIDs associated with a specific ActionTypeID? You're getting a vehicle that's operated by a specific driver with a count of number of actions done for that vehicle with a set status for the entire, I'm guessing, claim or file.  So you just want ActionTypeID | Total Distinct Actions Done?

Comment: I have tried to do this Felix, struggled with finding how to upload a file so hopefully an image will suffice,it should work using the link in the original post.

Comment: The columns headers would be Date, vehilceID, VehicleID, Not suitable, job Acknolowdged etc. The rows would read, on the 2/2/2016 driverid 123 in vehicleid 456 had 4 Not suitable, 6 Acknowledged, 2 Job accepted etc.  I hope this is making sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT  CONVERT (DATE,[ActionTime],103) AS [Date],
        VehicleID AS VehicleID,
        DriverID AS DriverID,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 7 THEN 1 END)  AS [Not Suitable],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 8 THEN 1 END)  AS [Job Acknowledged],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 9 THEN 1 END)  AS [Job Accepted],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 10 THEN 1 END) AS [Job Rejected],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 12 THEN 1 END) AS [Job Recall],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 66 THEN 1 END) AS [Child Fleet Logon],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTypeID = 67 THEN 1 END) AS [Child Fleet Logoff]
FROM    [TaxiHistory].[dbo].[Actions]
WHERE   actiontime BETWEEN '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
                   AND     '2016-02-02 23:59:59'
        AND ActiontypeID IN (7,8,9,10,12,66,67)
GROUP BY CONVERT (DATE,[ActionTime],103),
        VehicleID,
        DriverID
```

Comment: Thank you JamieD77

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    CONVERT (Date,[ActionTime],103) AS DATE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ActionID) AS Actions,
    VehicleID AS VehicleID,
    DriverID AS DriverID,
    [7] 'Not Suitable',
    [8] 'Job Acknowleged',
    [9] 'Job Accepted',
    [10] 'Job Rejected',
    [12] 'Job Recall',
    [66] 'Child Freet Logon',
    [67] 'Child Fleet Logoff'   
(
    select ActionTime, VehicleId, DriverId, ActionTypeId, count(*) as TotalType
    FROM [TaxiHistory].[dbo].[Actions]
    WHERE actiontime between '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-02 23:59:59'
      AND ActiontypeID IN (7,8,9,10,12,66,67)
    group by ActionTime, VehicleId, DriverId, ActionTypeId
pivot(sum(TotalType) for ActionTypeId in ([7],[8],[9],[10],[12], [66], [67])) 
) p
```

The inner query is the basic one, which gets the number of Actions for each ActionTime, Vehicle, Deiver and ActionType. The PIVOT on the end of that basically says for each of the ActionTypeId's listed, sum up the TotalType and put in a column in the result set with the name of the ActionTypeId's value. This result set (p on the query) is then the input to the outer select which takes the columns and puts various names to them.